# I want state to update, but no for the component to Re-render. Having some trouble

Tags: reactjs

The architecture of my page is like this:

Parent Component 
->
  (1) Carousel Slider Component
  (2) Zoom Button Component
  (3) Bunch of other components

Every time the Carousel Slider Component changes it's active index, it updates Parent Component's state.  I want to keep track of what the current active index is inside Parent Component.  However, this causes Parent Component and all it's child components to re-render.

If I add a componentShouldUpdate() function to the parent Component, the child components no longer re-render, but when I go to grab state to find out what the active slider index is, the state never changes either.

Is there a way to update the state without re-render the components?  Thanks

Comment: Could you share code of 'shouldComponentUpdate' method? Do you use PureComponent in your code?

Comment: Hi Chuve, the code is pretty simple.  It looks like this:
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return (nextState.activeSliderIndex === this.state.activeSliderIndex);
}

The parent component is a pure component, but it's children are subcomponents of it and are not.

Comment: if you need to keep track of state changes, the component needs to re render. if not then its a sync problem